# git workflow: merge branch B into feature branch A to help test A, but merge ONLY code from A during PR into main?

Tags: git, workflow

I have two feature branches that I am working on. Feature A and Feature B. Feature B has quality-of-life updates that are helpful, but not strictly necessary, for testing of any code, including that in Feature A. The code changes from feature B don't overlap with code for Feature A. In fact the differences between Feature B and Feature A and main are all contained in a single new file in this case (though more generally the split may not be so clean).

Finally, the difficult constraint is that feature B is low priority for other developers so it is unlikely to be able to be reviewed/merged into main before Feature A is reviewed (otherwise I could just merge B into main and then main into A).

Here's my imagined workflow:

- Merge Feature B into Feature A
- Do testing etc. of Feature A.
- When Feature A is ready for merging in to main I need to go ahead and manually delete all of the changes that are Feature B specific from Feature A.
- PR Feature A into main

The problem is the 3rd step feels a little hacky. In my specific case where the Feature B code is just it's own file this is fine. But if the code from Feature B was instead, perhaps, a class or a few functions embedded within some other file this could get to be a uncomfortable amount of work. Is there a better workflow to accomplish my goals (other than getting Feature B merged into main first)?

Answer (score 0):

This will be painful on day to day, for sure merge B before is the best.

You will need 3 branches
A
B
A+B

```
                  X---Y---Z   A
                 /         
            D---E  main
                 \
                  F---G---H    B
                 
                  X---Y---Z--   
                 /            \ 
            D---E---F---G---H--I A+B
```

you will work and test on A+B.
Then the fixes should be pushed in branch A.

You will spend time to switch between branches and the risk to mix up is here.

A way is to use `git commit --fixup` and `git rebase -i --autosquash main` to amend commit from branch A, you will modify commit `X`, `Y`, `Z`

You can also use git rebase -i to move your commit before the merge.

```
                  X---Y---Z--   
                 /            \ 
            D---E---F---G---H--I A+B
```

let say you do P commit `fixup! X`, Q should be added

```
git commit --fixup=<X sha> files
```

then

```
git commit #as usual
```

you will get

```
                  X---Y---Z--   
                 /            \ 
            D---E---F---G---H--I--P--Q
```

And you rebase with autosquash and you preserve the merge and you want interactif prompt:

```
git rebase --autosquash -i --rebase-merges
```

you will get

```
# Branch A                                          |~                                                    
reset onto                                          |~                                                    
pick c888803 X                                      |~                                                    
fixup 17c9a48 fixup! X                              |~                                                    
pick bba9c0a Y                                      |~                                                    
pick 931d75e Z                                      |~                                                    
label A                                             |~                                                    
                                                    |~                                                    
reset onto                                          |~                                                    
pick d6e5233 F                                      |~                                                    
pick a2852db G                                      |~                                                    
pick 231e819 H                                      |~                                                    
merge -C 712dfc2 A # Merge branch 'A'               |~                                                    
pick e8d3984 Q
```

then move Q to branch A, check the fixup

```
# Branch A                                          |~                                                    
reset onto                                          |~                                                    
pick c888803 X                                      |~                                                    
fixup 17c9a48 fixup! X                              |~                                                    
pick bba9c0a Y                                      |~
pick e8d3984 Q                                      |~                                                    
pick 931d75e Z                                      |~                                                    
label A                                             |~                                                    
                                                    |~                                                    
reset onto                                          |~                                                    
pick d6e5233 F                                      |~                                                    
pick a2852db G                                      |~                                                    
pick 231e819 H                                      |~                                                    
merge -C 712dfc2 A # Merge branch 'A'               |~
```

you will get

```
                  X---Y'---Q'---Z'   
                 /               \ 
            D---E---F---G---H-----I newA + B
```

to check all is good you will have A and B
then you need to force  branch A to Z'

```
git branch -f branchA shaZ'
```

Comment: you can also rebase A on top of B, do what you have to do and then rebase on main